# Adding values (interval text) on top discrete seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

How to add values(interval text) on top discrete `seekbar`.

**For example:-** I want to add 0-9(interval value) on top of `seekbar`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom View, like

```
public class NumberedSeekBar extends AppCompatSeekBar {
```

and in overriden `onDraw()`

```
barBounds.left = getPaddingLeft();
barBounds.top = labelBackground.getHeight() + getPaddingTop();
barBounds.right = barBounds.left + viewWidth - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
barBounds.bottom = barBounds.top + viewHeight - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();

progressPosX = barBounds.left + ((float) this.getProgress() / (float) this.getMax()) * barBounds.width();

labelPos.x = (int) progressPosX;
labelPos.y = getPaddingTop();

String labelText = this.getProgress() + "";

labelTextPaint.getTextBounds(labelText, 0, labelText.length(), labelTextRect);

canvas.drawText(labelText, (labelPos.x - pixelOffset) + labelBackground.getWidth() / 2 - labelTextRect.width() / 2, labelPos.y + labelBackground.getHeight() / 2 + labelTextRect.height() / 2, labelTextPaint);
```

Where `barBounds` is a `Rect`, made in Constructor, `labelPos` is a `Point` and `labelTextPaint` is some default Paint like

```
labelTextPaint = new Paint();
labelTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
labelTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
labelTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
labelTextPaint.setDither(true);
```